# how to get a graphical representation of a c++ code?

Tags: graphviz

I have used Doxigen + graphviz to get images from my code (C++ in Eclipse) but it doesn't reflect the code flow, I mean I want to get the code structures (if/else, the while) in the images....

Comment: maybe you could run your program and some tool could generate a uml sequence diagram of the execution flow

Answer (score 2):

The [CoFlo](http://sourceforge.net/projects/coflo/?source=navbar) open source utility can generate control flow graphs for C and C++. See their [live demo](http://coflo.sourceforge.net/wordpress-content/wp-content/new_report_sample/index.html).

Comment: Thanks Scott, I will investigate